# I just joined Puzzling, but can't post an answer

Tags: support, answers, protected-questions

I saw [a question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92734/almost-half-a-million-yet-smaller-than-hundred) that I wanted to post an answer to, so I joined Puzzling.

My reputation on other sites allowed me to immediately get the +100 bonus... which should allow me to answer the question. Yet, even after logging out, and logging in again, I still can't.

What's going on?

[image: 100 pts, yet not allowed to answer a question]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The association bonus doesn't count for protected questions (or "highly active questions", as they're now called). You need to earn 10 reputation *on this site* before that block disappears.

See also [Why is the Association Bonus ignored when trying to answer a protected question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170937/278659)